# AWS Step Function using Choice state isn't hitting all Task states

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I want to call the functions in the order first call, then second, third, fourth, and then end.

I am using the *choice* example in the AWS Management Console.

Why does third and fourth call not get hit?

#### AWS Step Function Code (JSON)

```
{
  "Comment": "state functionality",
  "StartAt": "FirstCall",
  "States": {
    "FirstCall": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Not": {
            "Resource": "rnName",
            "Variable": "$.response",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "ResultPath": "$",
            "OutputPath": "$",
            "StringEquals": "Success Import"
          },
          "Next": "SecondCall"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.response",
          "StringEquals": "Success Import ",
          "Next": "ThirdCall"
        },
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.response",
              "StringEquals": "Success Import"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.response",
              "StringEquals": "Success Import"
            }
          ],
          "Next": "FourthCall"
        }
      ]
    },
    "SecondCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "BeforeEnd"
    },
    "ThirdCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "BeforeEnd"
    },
    "FourthCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "BeforeEnd"
    },
    "BeforeEnd": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Because your `Next` value for the `SecondCall` is explicitly set to `BeforeEnd`.

Comment: Yes I have tried changing the next value for the second call to thirdcall...but that leaves the third call being called from the second and first call. I only want the third call to be called from the first call then to terminate this branch

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to call things in this order:

1. First
2. Second
3. Third
4. Fourth

... then I don't think you want to use the `Choice` state. The `Choice` state is specifically intended to allow you to make branching decisions, depending on the value of a property on the current state object. This is going to result in some branches being executed, while others are skipped.

By the way, since the `Choice` state isn't actually "calling" anything, I would recommend avoiding naming it "*call something*" as this might throw you off. The `Task` state is the only one that actually invokes any code, either through an AWS Lambda function, or the concept of a Step Functions "*Activity Task*".

You can edit your question if you'd like to clarify on what you're trying to accomplish.

Is this what you're trying to do instead?

[image: AWS Step Function]

```
{
  "Comment": "state functionality",
  "StartAt": "FirstCall",
  "States": {
    "FirstCall": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
          "Not": {
            "Resource": "rnName",
            "Variable": "$.response",
            "InputPath": "$",
            "ResultPath": "$",
            "OutputPath": "$",
            "StringEquals": "Success Import"
          },
          "Next": "SecondCall"
        },
        {
          "Variable": "$.response",
          "StringEquals": "Success Import ",
          "Next": "ThirdCall"
        },
        {
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.response",
              "StringEquals": "Success Import"
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.response",
              "StringEquals": "Success Import"
            }
          ],
          "Next": "FourthCall"
        }
      ]
    },
    "SecondCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "FirstCall"
    },
    "ThirdCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "FirstCall"
    },
    "FourthCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "BeforeEnd"
    },
    "BeforeEnd": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

If all you want to do is call four functions in order, then you'd use:

[image: AWS Step Functions]

```
{
  "Comment": "state functionality",
  "StartAt": "FirstCall",
  "States": {
    "FirstCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "SecondCall"
    },
    "SecondCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "ThirdCall"
    },
    "ThirdCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "FourthCall"
    },
    "FourthCall": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "Next": "BeforeEnd"
    },
    "BeforeEnd": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "rnName",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```